# Downloading multiple images using PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I want to download images from a web page, for example, www.yahoo.com, and store it in a folder using [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP).

I am getting the page source using file_get_contents() and extracting the img src tag. I am passing this src to [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) code. The code does not give any error, but the images are not getting downloaded. Please check out the code. I am not getting where I am going wrong.

```
<?php
    $html = file_get_contents('www.yahoo.com');
    $ptn = '/< *img[^>]*src *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i';
    preg_match_all($ptn, $html, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    $seq = 1;
    foreach($matches as $img)
    {
        $fp = fopen("root/Images/image_$seq.jpg", 'wb');
        $ch = curl_init ($img);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $img);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
        $image = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        fwrite($fp, $image);
        fclose($fp);
        $seq++;
    }
    echo "IMAGES DOWNLOADED";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($matches as $img)
```

should be changed to

```
foreach($matches[1] as $img)
```

BTW: you should replace the file_get_contents by cURL, it's about 3x as fast;)

Answer (score 0):

- Is $img the full [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) of the image?
- Is the image protected (use referer)?

  ```
  $image = false;
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 7);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,gzip);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
  $image = curl_exec ($ch);
  ```

Try debugging first.

First try it with a single image from Yahoo, `http://www.depers.nl/beeld/w100/2011/201105/20110510/anp/sport/img-100511-349.onlinebild.jpg`.

Also, why use file_get_contents and curl? Use curl instead.

1. Make a function for cURL: `function simple_curl ( $url,$binary=false){ set your cURL vars, return curl_exec)`.
2. Get yahoo.com: `$result = simple_curl($url);`
3. Get links with the pattern (check if the matches contains the full URL ( domain + directory + file ).
4. Loop each pattern match (don't forget: multi array!! So loop on `$matches[1]`).
5. curl binary file and save it: `$image = simple_curl($match,true);`

Answer (score 0):

- `www.yahoo.com` is not a URL, `http://www.yahoo.com/` is.
- $img is an array you need to iterate `$matches[1]`
- You both tell cURL to write to a file and retrieve the result. Use one.

I don't know how you don't see errors. I would look into that. Copying and pasting and then running it gave me plenty of errors.